# Example of a SOAP payload for IDEONE

Tags: soap

Has anyone got a sample SOAP payload for the ideone.com service?

I've tried several clients including the Firefox SOA client ( which returns an error from the service), the 360Works java soap client which crashes on reading the wsdl, and the online soapclient.com which returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried two of the SOAP clients you mentioned, soapclient.com and Firefox SOA, and successfully accessed the service at ideone.com.

First, make sure you are using the API password when trying the service and not the site password.

With soapclient.com, make sure that you're viewing the results as XML. You won't see anything if you choose HTML (one of their options).

With both clients, make sure you don't interpret the status with a key name of "error" as meaning that an error has been returned, if the value of this field is "OK". This indicates success.